# Op-amp with constant gain for small signal(mV)

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, measurement, gain, shunt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvxIAH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to measure current using shunt resistor and I want to amplify the voltage over the shunt using an op-amp. The shunt resistor gives 60mV @ 60A. I tried LTC 1050(http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1050fb.pdf) but for input <20mV the gain is not constant. The op-amp has a supply of +/5V. 
Vout is the signal that I want to send to ADC NI 9215, which has ±10 V measurement range and 16-bit resolution.
Do you know what features the op-amp should have for this purpose?
Which op-amp do you suggest to use?
Which circuit is the best for this application?

Thanks

Comment: There's no reason the gain would vary depending on just the input level.  Post your circuit and explain what makes you think the gain is changing.

Comment: Show the circuit you tried.

Comment: for input <20mV the gain is not constant I doubt that as this is highly unlikely assuming a proper design. Explain how you have come to this conclusion

Comment: I added the circuit and more details in the description.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I tried with bigger input voltage signal and the gain doesn't change.

Comment: No, show the complete circuit including the power rails and the load that takes 60 amps.

Comment: I completed the circuit, I want to measure negative and positive current.

Comment: Can you flip your voltage sources and batteries the correct way? It does not change anything electrically except for -5 V inverted, i.e. +5 V, but looks neater.

Comment: you didn't show the values measured but what you observed could just be due to offset.

Comment: @Andyaka what circuit do you suggest me to use to measure the current with shunt resistor?

Comment: Almost certainly it is a layout problem. How have you prototyped it. Circuit looks fine btw except you haven't shown decoupling caps or how the power to the amp is derived.

Comment: Andy maybe right about the layout problem. The for R2 is important, let me update the schematic to show how R2 needs to be connected (at GND side of the shunt resistor).

Comment: @FakeMoustache no, don't update the schematic, let the op show the layout his way because this would piss me off completely if I'd answered like Olin has. Roll that change back please.

Comment: @Andyaka You're right, done.

Comment: I can change my circuit, so if you some better circuit to use please tell me.

Comment: *you some better circuit to use please tell me* Read the comments: did anyone say the circuit is not OK ? There are many different circuits, want to try them all ? Or do you want to **learn and understand** what you did not do right ? This site is about **understanding and learning** if you want ready-made working solutions, hire an experienced EE.

Comment: Sorry @FakeMoustache,  I mean that if you know other better solution to measure the current I would like to know and understan why they are better of that I'm using.
I didn't understand why in my circuit the gain if not costant. Do you understand it?

Comment: No one said your circuit/solution is not OK. But it will only work OK if it is implemented in a proper way. The voltage across the shunt will be small and you're amplifying it a lot. Then proper grounding and routing is required. No clue if you have done that properly.

Comment: Can you explain better what I need to do, because I do not understand what you mean for routing. In which way shoud be done grounding? Sorry, I'm not expert.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know what features should have the op amp for this purpose?

for that particular circuit, you need dual supply (or a beyond-the-rail opamp), zero offset opamp. it is not a good circuit to measure current.

google current sense amplifier.

Comment: Maxim have some pretty decent current sensing amplifiers

Comment: Which is a good circuit to measure current?

Answer (score 0):

You need a opamp that includes ground in its common mode input range.  You didn't provide a link, so we don't know if the one you are using has this spec.

However, even for opamps that supposedly can handle input signals down to ground, it can often be a good idea to get them out of that region by providing a little negative supply.  Just a charge pump running from something that toggles often is good enough.  Sometimes it's easy to arrange for a microcontroller to put its clock on a spare output pin, for example.

### Update

You have now changed the description of your circuit to this schematic:

[image]

This is very unlikely to work.  A TL081 is inappropriate here.  Note that with ±15 V supply, its common mode input range is only ±11 V and its output voltage swing ±12 V with 10 kΩ load.  Put another way, it needs 4 V input headroom from each supply, and 3 V output headroom.  The datasheet doesn't say how this might scale to only a ±5 V supply, but probably not well at all.  This amp really isn't intended for only a ±5 V supply.

There are plenty of opamps that would work fine in this application with ±5 V supply, but the TL081 is not one of them.  You need to actually
**READ THE DATASHEET!**

Comment: this is the op amp
http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1050fb.pdf

Comment: @Anto Next time, type the opamp model in the schematic. You now see that it is assumed you used a TL081 which is unsuitable for this. But you used a different opamp. Then why draw a schematic where it says TL081 ? Details are important !

Comment: @Olin Lathrop do you think that if I substitute my op amp with TL081 the circuit will work correctly?

Comment: > do you think that if I substitute my op amp with TL081 the circuit will work correctly? the circuit, as is, should work. unfortunately, you have done a great job at preventing others from help you.